# get the value from a image tag of a xml to a xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

This is my xml code.I want to use the Image element value with Xslt so that i can use a image from the xml document.please help me how to get the image.I got all the other elements of xml through
xslt.My only problem is with the image transfering.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="work.xsl"?>
<student>
<studentlist>
    <S.No>1</S.No>
    <Name>Student1</Name>
    <E-mail>ab@xy.in</E-mail>
    <Qualification>MCA</Qualification>
    <createdon>6 Jan 2012</createdon>
    <Image><img src="/home/walkingtree/Desktop/hemanth practice/new/close-icon-41.jpg"/>
    <img src="/home/walkingtree/Desktop/hemanth practice/new/edit.jpg"/>
    </Image>
</studentlist>
<studentlist>
    <S.No>2</S.No>
    <Name>Student2</Name>
    <E-mail>cd@xy.in</E-mail>
    <Qualification>BE</Qualification>
    <createdon>7 Jan 2012</createdon>
    <Image><img src="/home/walkingtree/Desktop/hemanth practice/new/close-icon-41.jpg"/>
    <img src="/home/walkingtree/Desktop/hemanth practice/new/edit.jpg"/>
    </Image>
</studentlist>
<studentlist>
    <S.No>3</S.No>
    <Name>Student3</Name>
    <E-mail>ef@xy.in</E-mail>
    <Qualification>B.TECH</Qualification>
    <createdon>3 Jan 2012</createdon>
    <Image><img src="/home/walkingtree/Desktop/hemanth practice/new/close-icon-41.jpg"/>
    <img src="/home/walkingtree/Desktop/hemanth practice/new/edit.jpg"/>
    </Image>
</studentlist>
<studentlist>
    <S.No>4</S.No>
    <Name>Student4</Name>
    <E-mail>gh@xy.in</E-mail>
    <Qualification>MCA</Qualification>
    <createdon>23 Dec 2011</createdon>
    <Image><img src="/home/walkingtree/Desktop/hemanth practice/new/close-icon-41.jpg"/>
    <img src="/home/walkingtree/Desktop/hemanth practice/new/edit.jpg"/>
    </Image>
</studentlist>
</student>
```

this is my xslt code.its a bit lengthy but hope u will get it.i dont know whether in for-each loop i am using the correct format..plz help me with this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
<html>
<head>
<title>Login form</title>
<style>
input{
font: 1em sans-serif;
width: 300px;
box-sizing: border-box;
border: 1px solid #999;
}
.styled-select select {

}
#sel {
font: 1em sans-serif;
width: 230px;
height:31px;
box-sizing: border-box;
border: 2px solid #43C6DB;
height:31px;
background: #fafafa url("/home/walkingtree/Desktop/hemanth        practice/editalll/hello.jpg") no-repeat 100% 50%;
appearance:none;
 -webkit-appearance:none;
}
#form-setting{
display:none;
position:fixed;
left:620px;
top:5px;
width: 390px;
padding: 1em;
border: 1px solid #CCC;
border-radius: 15px 1px;
background-color:#BDEDFF;
}

form div + div {
margin-top: 1em;
}

label {
display: inline-block;
width: 110px;
text-align: left;
}

input{
 font: 1em sans-serif;
 width: 230px;
height:31px;
box-sizing: border-box;
border: 2px solid #43C6DB;
}
.button {
background-color: #89C35C;
border: none;
color: white;
padding: 10px 25px;
text-align: center;
text-decoration: none;
display: inline-block;
font-size: 16px;
margin: 4px 2px;
cursor: pointer;
border-radius:6px;
}
option{
height:20px;
}

.button2 {border-radius:6px;
background-color: #E55451;
float:right}

#close{position:fixed;
top:0px;
left:1040px;
cursor:pointer;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <table border="0" cellspacing="0" width="600px">
        <tr>
            <th>
                <div style="background-color:#EF8224">
                    <table width="100%">
                        <tr>
                            <th style="float:left"><font color="white">StudentList</font></th>
                            <th style="float:right"><a href="#" onclick="poped()">Add</a></th>
                            <th style="float:right"><img src="/home/walkingtree/Desktop/adding.png" width="17px" align="right"/></th>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table width="100%">
                    <tr bgcolor="#EF8224">
                        <th style="text-align:left" width="100px">S.No.      </th>
                        <th style="text-align:left">Name</th>
                        <th style="text-align:left">Email</th>
                        <th style="text-align:left">Qualification</th>
                        <th style="text-align:left">CreatedOn</th>
                        <th style="text-align:left">Action</th>
                    </tr>
                    <xsl:for-each select="student/studentlist">
                    <tr style="background-color:#FFDFD6">
                        <td><xsl:value-of select="S.No"/></td>
                        <td><xsl:value-of select="Name"/></td>
                        <td><xsl:value-of select="E-mail"/></td>
                        <td><xsl:value-of select="Qualification"/></td>
                        <td><xsl:value-of select="createdon"/></td>
                        <td><img width="25x" height="25px" src="{/student/studentlist/Image/node()}" class="CalloutRightPhoto"/></td>
                    </tr>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
 </div>
 <div id="form-setting">    
    <p>
        <img id="close" src="/home/walkingtree/Desktop/hemanth practice/editalll/close-icon-41.jpg" width="10px" height="10px" onclick="closeform()"/>
    </p>
    <form>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                     <div>
                            <label for="name">Name<font color="red">* </font>:</label>
                            <input type="text" id="name" name="user_name"/>
                     </div>
                     <div>
                            <label for="mail">E-mail<font color="red">*</font>:</label>
                            <input type="email" id="mail" name="user_mail"/>
                     </div>
                    <div>
                        <label for="qual">Qualification:</label>
                        <select id="sel">
                            <option value=""></option>
                                <option value="MCA">MCA</option>
                                <option value="B.Tech">B.Tech</option>
                        </select>
                        </div>
                </td>
            </tr>

                <tr style="width:100%">
                    <td align="right" style="float:right">
                        <button class="button">submit</button>
                        <button class="button button2">reset</button> 
                    </td>
                </tr>

        </table>
    </form>
 </div>
<script type="text/javascript">
var v=document.getElementById("form-setting");
function poped(){
v.style.display="block";
}
function closeform(){
v.style.display="none"
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

this is my output that i got from this code.as u can see action doesnt display any picture
 [this is the output i got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0U6E5.png)

this is the output i need to get.
    [see the action column of actual table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g2bK2.png)

Comment: Hello,in my code as u can see there are other fields i got all the values i have problem with image.

Comment: Please clarify what you want to achieve and what you have tried so far. Post the XSLT code that causes you problems and the desired output you try to generate.

Comment: @Thomas W updated my question ..hope u will understand

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with this line:

```
<img width="25x" height="25px" src="{/student/studentlist/Image/node()}" class="CalloutRightPhoto"/>
```

Firstly, by starting the expression with `/` you have made it an absolute path, based on the top-level document node, so this won't select the image relative to the current student.

Secondly, you have multiple images, so you really need an `xsl:for-each` (or `xsl:apply-templates` here.

Thirdly, you need to reference the `src` attribute to get the image path you need.

Try replacing it with this....

```
<xsl:for-each select="Image/img">
    <img width="25px" height="25px" src="{@src}" class="CalloutRightPhoto"/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Note the use of [Attribute Value Template](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#attribute-value-templates)s in creating the `src` attribute for the `img` element. The curly braces indicate an expression to be evaluated, so doing `{@src}` means get the value of the `src` attribute in the current `img` element.

If you want to add `onclick` actions to the images, you can, but you will need a way to distinguish between the images. Perhaps something like this..

```
<xsl:for-each select="Image/img">
    <img width="25px" height="25px" src="{@src}" class="CalloutRightPhoto">
        <xsl:attribute name="onclick">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="contains(@src, 'close-icon-41.jpg')">
                    <xsl:text>doClose();</xsl:text>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:text>doEdit();</xsl:text>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </img>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: thanks fro the answer.This is what i was looking for..Can u please explain how the src works.And can that images be added with any onclick fucntions and if yes how can you do it..thanks in advance

Comment: I've expanded my answer to explain a bit more.

Comment: Thank you @Tim C .This code solves my problem.So in above code u gave attribute name="onclick" .So this name is it a inbuilt one and in conatins src it is not required to mention whole path of the image??

Comment: this is my another question.If u can assit with some help with this it would be great.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45584735/how-to-get-data-from-the-form-of-an-xslt-into-the-existing-xml-without-the-previ

Comment: That was just an example. If you images require different actions, you will need a way to identify what action goes with which image.

Comment: yeah i got that..my question is at the place of direct image can we place the whole image path??